# Firebug not showing Javascript Files

Tags: firebug

I have firebug 2.0.18 and Firefox 50.0

All of the sudden firebug stopped showing javascript files for every page I visit.
I was working on my application when I needed to debug a script but I got this error:

> If  tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal
>   "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be
>   parsable (syntactically correct).

At first I thought it was an error on my application. But then I noticed that firebug is not showing scripts in any website, not just mine.

I tried disabling and enabling the scripts tab again, also disabling and enabling firebug, uninstalling and installing firebug again, closing firefox and even restarting the computer.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broken Script panel is obviously a [known issue](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8057) related to Firefox 50.0+.

Though as [written on the Firebug homepage](https://getfirebug.com/), **the development and maintenance of Firebug are discontinued**.

Instead, Firebug users are advised to switch to the Firefox DevTools (which now provide a Firebug theme to make the transition easier). See also the [related blog post](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/)